# Enroll Mok after driver change

Tags: drivers

So I change my driver (Nvidia 470) to Nvidia 460. It asked me to define a password for Mok.

Upon restating I choose continue to boot instead of enroll Mok. Now I want to revert to 470 and the same scenario appeared. This time I choose to enroll in Mok and placed the password. Will my Nvidia driver be loaded correctly or do I need to do something else?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Once the MOK is enrolled, the driver should load correctly.
Possibly when you skipped it before, the 460 driver did not actually load.

You can check with `lsmod | grep nvidia`  and run `modinfo` on one of the listed modules to get the version.

Answer (score -1):

Your driver should be correctly loaded.

You can check your Nvidia driver using these methods:

- Terminal: Open the terminal and type `nvidia-smi`
- GUI: Open the applications menu and search for `NVIDIA X Server Settings`